# ogr2ogr latitute longitude conversion formats

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, well-known-text

trying to convert shape files into mysql tables. Able to create table and load data successfully using OGR2OGR. Only challenge I see is latitude/longitude is not exactly the same format as one of my developer (no longer there) who did the conversion for me. Other than geometry shape, rest of the values are exactly matching.

For the same record my conversion shows
LINESTRING (3015615.1663366337 13849435.592079207,3015602.495049505 13849789.215841584)

My developer conversion shows
'LINESTRING(-95.69831901099997 29.789630642000077,-95.69832747399994 29.79060369800004)',3

what am I missing ? what should I do convert my shapefile into the format my devloper got it. Tried to convert into .csv as well but getting the same result.

Comment: I posted this question after lot of research and couldn't find answer. But as soon as I post I found partial answer (hurray !!). http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64535/how-to-convert-x-y-coordinates-to-longitude-latitude-using-quantumgis      I was able to convert X,Y co0ordinates into Lat/long, Now my remaining part of question is how to get the SRID in the above question where my developer have value of '3'..how to get that value when converting from shapefile

Comment: Your coordinate values are not not  lat/lon they are projected.  Please edit your question and add the output of `ogrinfo` for the original shapefile and the existing mysql layer.

Comment: When you **edit* your question to revise it with the additional details and perhaps think about whether having solved the first part means that there are some details you posted that are now no longer relevant.  Also, as a new user, be sure to take the [Tour].