# In which format am I working and how can I plot it correctly on GIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, format

I've been working recently replicating this paper: ["Constructing Street Networks from GPS trajectories"](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~mahmed/Publications/csm_esa2012.pdf). They got a repository with the implemented [code](https://github.com/pfoser/mapconstruction/tree/master/algorithms/Ahmed). Anyway, the issue is that their data is in the following format:

```
391821.292854,5821122.049075
```

Reading carefully the code and the paper I have figured out that these coordinates are in meters after Mercator projection and are probably in [ESRI format](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64535/converting-x-y-coordinates-to-longitude-latitude-using-qgis?newreg=882a76004fd94981b901c5d9ba5ba89d).

The problem that I have is that I cannot figure it out how to plot them correctly on QGIS. The file that I have is on txt. I'm using the Delimited Text plug in to import the data and playing with the CRS configuration without results. The data appears nowhere near Berlin (where the data is from)

Comment: It is in CSV or Tab delimited text format.

Comment: You need to figure out what coordinate reference system the coordinates are in. You're partway there in knowing that it's a mercator projection with the units in meters, but that's not quite enough information. Look in the metadata and see if you can find an EPSG code, it would look something like `EPSG:3857`. An EPSG code is a way of unambiguously defining the coordinate reference system.

Comment: It looks like UTM. Try EPSG:32633 which is WGS84 UTM 33 North. It might be on ETRS89 instead (3045), but they're equal within about a meter.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! That was exactly the one I needed, how did you know???

Comment: There isn't really anything called "Esri format" though they have created many formats over the years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two points here:

**1. File format**
The [original files](https://github.com/pfoser/mapconstruction/tree/master/data/tracks) are space-separated text files (i.e. similar to csv, but with a space instead of a comma acting as a separator).
The example you mention (`391821.292854,5821122.049075`) is a plain CSV instead.

**2. Projection**
These files seem to be UTM, and since proper metadata are missing, I would infer the correct EPGS code from the file names:

- Athens -> UTM zone 34N, maybe EPSG:4815 or EPSG:32635
- Berlin -> UTM zone 33N
- Chicago -> UTM zone 16N (EPSG:32616)

A quick check with a reliable map (Google Satellite will do) will confirm whether the choice is the right one ;)

Just activate the imported CSV layer and use a Google Satellite map as backdrop: if the points are where you expect them to be, to some degree it is a validation that the EPSG Code/UTM Zone is the correct one.

If, on the other hand, your waypoints are in the middle of an ocean or run over buildings, it is a good hint that you need to revise the projection parameters :D

*Please not that this "check" is not a real validation, just a way to exclude some obvious mistakes in the properties of the layer.*

Comment: Thank you really much for your help. It was pretty useful! I'm just getting into this kind of stuff and it's a little bit hard.

Comment: Were those the correct EPGS codes/UTM zones?

Comment: Yes! Was exactly that one. But I didn't understand so well the thing of checking in a reliable map :(

Comment: I see, check out if the edited version makes more sense ;)