# Converting WGS to latitude and longitude in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

How do you convert the WGS coordinate to latitude and longitude?

[image]

Comment: Have you read this post? [Converting x y coordinates to longitude latitude using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64535/converting-x-y-coordinates-to-longitude-latitude-using-qgis)

Comment: Coordinates in WGS84 are already lat/long. This must be something like a UTM coordinate based on the WGS84 datum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create new columns of type text with the following field calculator code:

```
to_dms(x(transform($geometry,'EPSG:source','EPSG:4326')),'x',3)
```

This gives you the X-coordinate in DMS-format with 3 decimal places. For the Y-coordinate just exchange both `x` for `y`.

Also, exchange the "source"-part in `EPSG:source` with the EPSG-code for the CRS your data is in.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100473/discussion-on-answer-by-erik-how-to-convert-wgs-to-latitude-and-longitude-in-qgi).