# Export shapefile into CSV file in order to extract coordinate only

Tags: shapefile, export, coordinates, csv

I have a [shapefile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s52r-NOPeUzmLgQmARaQKOPnJGUEsG_o/view?usp=sharing) which I can view in [Mapwindow5](https://github.com/MapWindow/MapWindow5),

[image]

But I need the co-ordinates only for my analysis. I've never used shapefile or geodata before. Is there any way to convert the shapefile into a CSV file? I didn't find any export option in Mapwindow5.

How can I do this?

---

I open the shapefile using the qgis and got this,

[image: map2]

The coordinate looks very strange. After some analysis, I knew that it was VICGRID 1994 co-ordinate system. And I didn't manage to find any option to export that into latitude and longitude.

Comment: If you don't find a solution in Mapwindow5, you can use QGIS for that.It's opensource: https://www.qgis.org/

Comment: This is a very common and easy task for a GIS. You could use QGIS as @Babel suggest but you could also use ArcMap\ArcPro if you have those installed, then its simply using the [Add XY Coordinates](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-xy-coordinates.htm) tool.

Comment: If I am not wrong then XY Coordinates won't be the same as lat/lon? Isn't it? I am installing `qgis`, but it's a large file (as my internet is super slow :) ). @Hornbydd Is there any export option in `qgis`?

Comment: The XY tool creates the XY values in the native coordinate system, so if the data was actually lat/long then you get those. I think that's pretty standard in any GIS system. Have tried typing into this forum search bar on how to export xy in qgis...

Comment: I got XY values in VICGRID 1994 co-ordinate. But for my work I badly need that in lat/long format. I search for any convert tool which can help me to get lat/long, but couldn't manage. Sorry to bother you, but can you suggest how can I do so? and thanks for your responses.

Comment: Add Lats and Longs with the Field Calculator like [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377208/expression-to-transform-xy-coordinates-to-latlong-in-qgis)